# Cast char* to my string implicitly

Tags: c++

I have my own string class (`DinString`), nothing special.
I was wondering is possible to do something like this

```
DinString a= "Helo World";

bool Func(DinString string);

Func("test");
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is. Simply implement an appropriate (non-`explicit`!) constructor:

```
class DinString {
public:
    DinString( const char *s ) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Please note that this won't work if you 'chain' more than one constructor like this. For instance, the following *does not work*:

```
class DinString {
public:
    DinString( const char *s ) {
        // ...
    }
};

class FooString {
public:
    FooString( const DinString & ) { }
};

void f( const FooString &) { }

f( "hello" ); // doesn't call FooString(DinString("hello!")); !
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a constructor to do this conversion for you:

```
class DinString {
  DinString(const char *string) { 
    // do something useful here
  }
};
```

This works because `DinString a= "Helo World";` is not an assignment (despite appearances) and is actually equivalent to writing `DinString a("Hello World");`

Answer (score 1):

Yes provide a conversion constructor for your class which `const char *` as input.

```
DinString::DinString(const char *);
```